# Add row in multiple-column listview?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, multiple-columns

I am having trouble adding a row that displays all the values of the member of an object.

Here is how I have set up my listview:

```
    <ListView Height="178" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="238,31,0,0" Name="SpoolSheetListView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="555" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="85"  Header="Column 1" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Column 2" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Column 3" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Column 4" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="115" Header="Column 5" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

say, myObject has 5 members: member1 to member5, which are all of type string. How do I add a single row in the ListView for that object?

Thanks again people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF list controls work best when you use them with data binding; you should bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` to a list of objects, and bind each column to a property of these objects.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Height="178" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="238,31,0,0" Name="SpoolSheetListView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="555" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="85"  Header="Column 1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Member1}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Column 2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Member2}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Column 3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Member3}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Column 4" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Member4}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="115" Header="Column 5" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Member5}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

(`Items` being a property of the `DataContext` that returns a collection of objects)

To add a row to the `ListView`, you just need to add an item to the `Items` collection (note that the collection should implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` so that the `ListView` is notified; the `ObservableCollection<T>` class works fine for most cases)

Comment: Hi Thomas! Thanks for your help! Do you mind, if you have the time, to show me in code how to implement INotifyCollectionChanged and ObservableCollection<T> in this case? I am sort of a newbie and would really appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: @will0809, you don't have to implement INotifyCollectionChanged, ObservableCollection<T> already does it. Just use an ObservableCollection<T> rather than a List<T>